# Value of EditText

Tags: android, xml

I first have this view in XML, in this file I need an `onClick` event to execute a simple Toast, the method is called join:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hrizi.onescore.community">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/apptoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="16dp">

            <!--First name-->
            <!--last name-->

            <!--Date of Birth -->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/ti_dateofbirth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_dateofbirth"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Date of birth"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/inputcolor" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!--title-->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/ti_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Title"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/inputcolor" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!--University-->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/ti_university"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_university"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="University"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/inputcolor" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!--About me-->
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/ti_aboutme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_aboutme"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="About me"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/inputcolor" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_join"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:background="@color/coloronscore"
                android:text="Join us"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:onClick="join"/>


            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_forgot_password"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the other Java file I have the following code:

```
package com.example.hrizi.onescore;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.hrizi.onescore.model.Transcriber;
import com.example.hrizi.onescore.utils.Constants;

import rx.subscriptions.CompositeSubscription;

public class community extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_community);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Join Our Community !");

        }

        //initializeViews();

    }

    public void join(View view)
    {
        Snackbar.make(view, Constants.EMAIL ,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        EditText title_Text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ti_title) ;
        String title = title_Text.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(community.this,"title",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And the problem that the Toast never appears and the application crashes.

Comment: add crash log..

Comment: `EditText title_Text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ti_title) ;` This could be the cause of crash. See subham's answer.

Comment: does the application crashed when you want to run it or after when you press the event?

Comment: How, possibly, you cannot solve this issue for two days? You cannot check the logs? Every simple crash point to the specific line where exception occurred.You cannot check that specific line in your code? Have just a little effort...

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
public class community extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
EditText title_Text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_community);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    title_Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ti_title) ;  // here changes

    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Join Our Community !");

    }

    //initializeViews();

}

public void join(View view)
{
    Snackbar.make(view, Constants.EMAIL ,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String title = title_Text.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(community.this,"title",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ti_title is actually a TextInputLayout not a EditText. This can be the reason for crash. Change the line:-

```
EditText title_Text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.title) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**I can see two things in your code**

```
1) "R.id.ti_title" belongs to "TextInputLayout" not "EditText"
2) You cannot find id of your "EditText" from onClick(View v) [assuming you are passing this view object on button click in join(View view)]
```

**How to resolve**

```
public class community extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
EditText title_Text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_community);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    title_Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title); // Modified Line 

    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Join Our Community !");    
    }

    //initializeViews();    
}

 public void join(View view)
 {
    Snackbar.make(view, Constants.EMAIL ,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String title = title_Text.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(community.this,title,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

Hope this help you somehow...